# In Bash, is it possible to pass in a first argument and then remove the extension while keeping the file path?

Tags: bash

Suppose we have `/path/to/my/file.gz.gg` and I would like to get only `/path/to/my/file.gz`

I tried to use the alias:

```
alias myalias="echo ${1%.gz}"
```

and run

```
myalias /path/to/my/file.gz.gg
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AKAIK alias doesn't take arguments like functions or scripts, so you cannot use `$1` argument, there's your problem.

Also, if it could, the dollar sign isn't escaped, so it's replaced on the fly when creating your alias command.

Here are two equivalent solutions:

1. Wrap your alias in a function so you get to use `$1` variable:

**You end up with this oneliner that does the job:**

```
`alias myalias='fn(){ echo "${1%.gg}"; unset -f fn; }; fn'`
```

This would create a temporary function fn, that can take an argument, execute the function then unset it so you don't get ghost functions on your current shell.

2. **Another solution**: Use a wrapper script

An equivalent solution might be a simple script, eg `/usr/local/bin/myalias` containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "${1%.gg}"
```

So your command `myalias /path/to/my/file.gz.gg` will work.
Don't forget to `chmod +x` the myalias script.dd

Answer (score 1):

you can strip the .gg

```
echo "${1%.gg}"
```

Comment: I tried doing `alias myalias="echo "${1%.gg}""` but it still returns the extension. Can this be put into an alias?

Answer (score 1):

First, this pattern `%.gz` won't work, you need this `%.*` or this `//.gg/` and this have to be in a function

```
myfunction () { echo ${1%.*}; }

$ myfunction /path/to/my/file.gz.gg
/path/to/my/file.gz
```

And this function can be an alias)

```
alias myalias=myfunction

$ myalias /path/to/my/file.gz.gg
/path/to/my/file.gz
```